# libpq behavior with hostname with multiple addresses and target_session_attrs=primary

Tags: postgresql, libpg

I have configured primary and hot standby PostgreSQL server. The replication works fine with repmanager. All I need to achieve is to keep the client connection string using a common hostname and not to change due to role change. To simply, my need the details are as follows.

Primary host: host1.home.network, IP: 192.168.0.2
Standby host: host2.home.network, IP: 192.168.0.3
Common host: myapphost.home.network: this resolves to IP: 192.168.0.2 and IP: 192.168.0.3

The connection string I want my app to use is:

user@localnode:~> psql "host=myapphost.home.network dbname=appdb sslmode=require target_session_attrs=primary"

But when I test the connection multiple times, I have observe strange behaviour and I am not sure if that's the expectation. The client application uses the myapphost.home.network. By using target_session_attrs=primary, my expectation is to connect to primary node all the time, no matter which one it is due to manual role change, either host1 or host2.home.network

The reason of having two IPs to common hostname is, sometimes we manually perform the role switch using repmanager. And because of this, I do not want any changes to client connection and I expect attribute target_session_attrs will always hook client connection to primary node. But after testing few times, I get error:

connection to server at "myapphost.home.network" (192.168.0.3), port 5432 failed: server is in hot standby mode

Now here my expectation is, despite myapphost.home.network resolves to two different servers (primary and slave/standby), because of using attribute target_session_attrs=primary, why my session does not get redirected to only primary host? And of course load_balance_hosts default value is disable.

Any guidance any appreciated.

Thanks

I tested the connection string multiple times, checked the various posts but unfortunately didnt succeed to find the right answer

Comment: "Why?" - I guess because it is implemented that way. Put the two host names and ports in the connection string.

Comment: I would like to avoid asking multiple applications to edit the connection string to specify all hosts, host1,host2 etc... This gives me flexibility to remove / add hosts if I can simply add or remove it from my DNS myapphost.home.network.  If I add new server, I simply add it to myapphost.home.network or remove vice versa.

Comment: Well, looks like you cannot do that. You could [get the connection string from an LDAP server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ldap.html) or write to the pgsql-hackers mailing list and tell them your enhancement request. I think that would be an interesting feature.

Comment: I think I will write to mailing list as a feature request, may be sometime in future we shall have it and I am sure it will be useful.

Many thanks for all comments

Comment: I don't know that the client can automatically tell if round-robin dns is in use.That means (a) you will need to repeat DNS requests from the client and see if you get the same one back and (b) make sure that you (and nothing between you + the dns server) do not cache DNS results. It should be do-able, but it's likely not elegant.

Comment: My expectations would be, driver knows how many addresses the host resolves to and what type of connection I need. So internally validating which one qualifies my need, driver may circle through hosts (in round robin fashion) and hook me to right sever rather than client doing retries. Of-course with this approach the connection establishment will take time. And depending number of host resolutions and number of standbys in list, it will affect the connection time. The only thing is, large number of hosts under DNS will kill the connection time.